# How to prevent re fresh page on java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

After hitting a download button, my page keep opening a new tab .

```
function download_(obj){
    // Generate download of hello.txt file with some content
    console.log('download');

    dockey = $(obj).attr("data-id);
    console.log('dockey',dockey);
    var url = ahmfaacr001_url_root + '/download-image?dockey='+dockey;
    var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
    win.focus();


}
```

Comment: you ask it to open a new tab and you do not want it to open a new tab?

Comment: my page keeping on refresh

Comment: change window.open(url, '_blank') to window.open(url, '_self');
check my answer below

Comment: `window.open(url, '_blank');` -> `_blank` means to open in a new tab/window. change it to `self`

Comment: Title says 'refresh page' , but the issue is about 'dont opening a new tab when you download a file via javascript' they are not related. In addition to that the function providad is not generic. It expect an object with some keys that you didnt specified for the community and it uses jQuery.

So please update the post with a proper title & content with the jquery version, a sample case and a jsfiddle/codepen or similar  platform with a live sample to be able to test and be able to help you

Comment: Which "page"? The one with the download button or the new tab?

Comment: @HéctorLeón title is "prevent refresh" - but there's no way to tell just *what* the actual issue on such limited, vague information; OP certainly hasn't said it's a problem downloading a file (or indeed that this is not the issue).  Also, please recommend a Stack Overflow Snippet, not a 3rd-party site such as jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't get demotivated with negative votes.
if following doesn't satisfy you, please elaborate your question.
explain what you want.
your question is about refresh, and we don't see anything about refresh.

```
function download_(obj){
    // Generate download of hello.txt file with some content
    console.log('download');

    dockey = $(obj).attr("data-id);
    console.log('dockey',dockey);
    var url = ahmfaacr001_url_root + '/download-image?dockey='+dockey;
    var win = window.open(url, '_self');
    win.focus();


}
```

or you can also go with (window.location.href = "webpage.htm";)
in your e.g.

```
window.location.href = url;
```

Comment: it stay on same page  but wont downloading

Answer (score 0):

The `_blank` parameter instructs the browser to open the URL in a new tab. I don't know if that is what you call a "refresh".

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
```

to

```
var win = window.open(url);
```